# How do I switch between remote github branches and local branches/folders with ease?

Tags: python, git, github, scrapy

### What's going to happen?

I got a big amount of Scrapy crawlers, written in Python 2.7. I need to convert them all to support Python 3.
This transition must be done completely in 1 go. I can only start using the Python 3 crawlers once they're all ready for deployment. I cannot deploy 1 crawler at a time.

### What have I done/what do I have?

I currently have a remote branch, which is the master branch. **Lets call that Remote-A**. That is the branch that holds all the crawlers, and they get executed daily. This branch must remain functional.

For that remote branch, I have the local folder/branch, where I fix bugs and create new ones. **Lets call that Local-A.** From the master, I push and pull from that.

Now, as "all operations must remain active", I need a separate remote branch for Python 3 crawlers. **That branch can be called Remote-B.** I've created that manually, so the whole repository has two branches now: Master(Remote-A), and the one for Python 3 crawlers(Remote-B), which is a copy of the Master branch.

I've also created a folder manually, and downloaded a zip from the Python 3 branch. **That folder is called Local-B.** My idea is to either delete all the (2.7) crawlers from Python 3 branch, or just start replacing them one by one.

To sum it up. I got Local A connected to Remote A. I also need Local B connected to Remote B. These two connections should not get mixed.

**Mind you**, I'm not very comfortable with GIT, and I'm the only responsible for the transition project, so I want everything to go smooth as silk. I know that it's easy to cause a lot of damage in GIT.

**So, my workflow requires me to keep the running crawlers operational on daily basis, and work on upgrading the old ones to Python 3. How do I make the switches between A- and B-sides easy, without causing a havoc?**

Comment: `I know that it's easy to cause a lot of damage in GIT.` Meh. Maybe, but git always provides a way to repair it.

Comment: @kowsky Complete offtopic, but: well, not always. `git reset` could damage uncommitted changes add or not added to the index, and `git clean` could delete important untracked files. Alas, [g]it happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question, I am afraid you are a bit confused about the concepts of branch and remote. A remote would be github, and also a local mirror of your git repo.

You can have as many mirrors as you like. All would contain all the branches.

In your case, and also if I understand your question, I would do as follows:

1. have a *deploy* branch (which what you seem to name as *Remote-A* - a name that is confusing to me): this branch should always be correct
2. have a python2 development branch (suggested name: *py2dev*), in case you need to perform modifications in the python2 deployed code before deploying the python3 code
3. have a python3 migration branch (suggested name: *py3*) where you would be migrating the python2 code

While the python3 migration is **not** ready, you would develop on the *py2dev* branch in your computer. In case you want to publish some change, you would publish these changes in your remote (i.e. github), and then pull these changes from that remote (github) in your deployed repo.

When the python3 migration is ready, you would push your changes again to a remote, and then fetch them, and do a `git checkout py3` in the deployed server. If things go wrong, you can do a `git checkout deploy` and you would be safe again.

There are many git workflows. This is supposed to be a simple one.

Comment: I might very well be confused about the correct terms and how Git works. I'll try to picture all this in my head and get back to this answer. Thank you! So far everything I do with git, is basicly pushing and pulling from few local folders to single branch in github.

Comment: It's normal that you are confused, it happened to me too. I recommend that you practice a bit with some dumb repositories and remotes (including github, but also local mirrors and remotes in other computers in your own LAN). Then you will see how a remote and a branch are different things. It can be complicated, but it is also powerful.